# How to reset \captionsetup{} to default after changing it before in the document

Tags: captions

I have already successfully changed the \captionsetup{} of my document to a different format provided in the code below. However, I need to come back to the original \captionsetup{} but it does not clear the previous specification and come back to default. I need help with this. Below is a minimal working example (MWE) that should be working on Overleaf, but it doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{A default caption.}
  \label{fig:default}
\end{figure}

% Change the caption setup
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, textfont=it}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{A custom caption.}
  \label{fig:custom}
\end{figure}

% Clear the caption setup
\captionsetup{}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Back to default caption.}   % This caption stays the same as the previous one
  \label{fig:backToDefault}   
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am using XeLaTeX to compile the project taking into account the need of it to use Arial as main text font.

Comment: Use `\captionsetup` inside a group. This way it will only change the captions until the end of the group

Comment: Hi! I am not user how to use it inside a group, could you be more specific? Thanks a lot, I have been a round this issue for hours.

Comment: I posted an answer which shows the code.

Comment: This is just great, it really does the trick! Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to change the caption for a single figure or for multiple figures?

Comment: I want to change the caption for multiple figures before resetting it to default

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\captionsetup` inside a group (`{...}`, `\begingroup ... \endgroup` etc.). This way it will only change the captions until the end of the group:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{A default caption.}
  \label{fig:default}
\end{figure}

\begingroup
% Change the caption setup
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, textfont=it}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{A custom caption.}
  \label{fig:custom}
\end{figure}
\endgroup

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Back to default caption.}
  \label{fig:backToDefault}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why not directly inside the figure? The environment is a "natural" group.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Arg, that was too easy to think off :) Can you please post an answer and I'll delete this one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Turns out, they want to change multiple captions